# Select title from table bound up with other column in this table

Tags: mysql

There is a table with columns: id, parent_id, title.
I have to make query which return titles and parent titles.
In one query i can select title and id of parent title, but not title and parent title,
Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT child.title  AS child_title
     , parent.title AS parent_title
FROM TableX AS child
  JOIN TableX AS parent
    ON parent.id = child.parent_id
```

Answer (score 0):

for one level you can do this (or more levels, just add another join) >

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.title, 
    b.title AS parent_title
FROM 
    table AS a
LEFT JOIN 
    table AS b ON
        b.id = a.parent_id
```

if you have multi levels, then it is better to just select all data, and build an array with parents (in you program), it is faster!